# Run curl from a perl scripts

Tags: macos, perl

I'm trying to use curl from a perl script using a piped open format:

```
my @cmd = ('curl', '-u','username:password', '-g','-T', "$upfile","mydomain/directory");
die '@cmd must have more than one element' unless @cmd>1;
open my $fh,'-|', @cmd or die $!;
close $fh or die $! ? $! : $?;
```

but am getting this error

```
curl: (23) Failed writing body
```

Running macOS 13.3. Anyone shed some light please?

Comment: A better way would be to use the ftp module from CPAN https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP rather than external programs

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I feel a bit embarassed. In the URL string I neglected to include the protocol 'ftp://'. DUH

This process AKA 'IPC' Inter-process Communication is something I've not heard of but disovered it at https://www.perlmonks.org/? under ‘2. Use a Piped open’ doing resarch on curl.

Apologies to all who may have run into this rabbit hole.